# Discord Python Kick Function not working after a certain time

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So I am making a captcha bot in discord.py and Im trying to kick the user if they dont answer the captcha in a specific amount of time rahter if they get it incorrect or if they dont type. If they get it correct it already will break the loop and that part works. Its just the time issue where it wont kick the user after a specific amount of time if they dont guess the captcha in that given time. I put 10 seconds just for testing. On the last two lines is their any way I can have that work where it will kick the user if they dont answer the captcha in that given time. Everything else works by the way and theirs no error**But heres the code:

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import random
import time
import asyncio
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="+", intents=intents)
@bot.command()
async def setup(ctx):
  embed=discord.Embed(title="How to get verfiied", 
  description="1.Go to the verified channel and use the command $verify\n2.Then from there you should be able to get you role and come into the server.\n\n**YOU HAVE 3 tries and only 15 minutes to solve the captcha or else the bot will kick you. Plesae contact staff if you have any issues**", color=0x0000FF)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.command(name='verify', pass_context = True)
async def verify(ctx):
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.message.channel
    image = ("captcha 6.png","captcha10.png","captcha11.png","captcha2.png", "captcha3.png", "captcha4.png", "captcha5.png", "captcha7.png","captcha8.png", "captcha9.png")
    image_random = random.choice(image)
    number = ("b3xpn", "2yggg","ydg8n","pp546","fcne6","cdfen","4f8yp","m8m4x","pdyc8","55w5c","xwx7d")
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(image_random))
    await ctx.send('Please solve the captcha image')
 
    for i in range(0, 3):
        guess = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
        if guess.content in number:
            await ctx.send('Correct Welcome!')
            role = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.roles, name="member")
            await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
            break
          
        else:
            await ctx.send("Incorrect")

    else:
        await ctx.send("Incorrect this is your 3rd try please rejoin and try again")
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        await ctx.author.kick()

    asyncio.sleep(5)
    await ctx.author.kick()
```

Comment: not really a huge issue but your code does not stop the function if the user does/does not respond therefore the last 2 lines would always run and kick the user even if they respond

Answer (score 0):

Idk if this will fix it or if that is just an post mistake but you are missing `await`at
`asyncio.sleep(5)`

Comment: That would not cause any issues but without await it would not sleep and go to the next line immediately

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `timeout` parameter with `wait_for()` or it will wait for answers for infinite time.

```
try:
    for i in range(0, 3):
        guess = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=20)
        # it will stop listening for messages after 20 seconds
        if guess.content in number:
            await ctx.send('Correct Welcome!')
            role = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.roles, name="member")
            await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
            break
          
        else:
            await ctx.send("Incorrect")

    else:
        await ctx.send("Incorrect this is your 3rd try please rejoin and try again")
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        await ctx.author.kick()

except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await ctx.author.kick()
```

Comment: also as @HamsterRecords said, u gotta put `await` in `asyncio.sleep(5)`